# My regular expression is not being cool

Tags: php, regex

My current one works almost perfectly but it misses out any other digits after a character like - or /.
The Original String is something like:

```
#!012 , #!02/09#!011 #!04-072
```

My current one works on stuff like:
 `$viewedResult = preg_replace('/#!([0-9A-Z]{1,4})/', '<a href="updateMooring.php?Number2=${1}&id='. $id .'">${1}</a>', $viewedResult);`
This would give me something like:

```
<a href="updateMooring.php?Number2=04&amp;id=db335b">04</a>-072<br />
```

but I want the "-072" in the Number2 bit like:

```
<a href="updateMooring.php?Number2=04-072&amp;id=db335b">04-072</a>
```

It could also be able to include /072s:

```
<a href="updateMooring.php?Number2=04/072&amp;id=db335b">04/072</a>
```

Any ideas? Remember that there is a #! in front of the number!

Comment: Could you show the original string before replace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
preg_replace('~#!([0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z/-]{0,5})~', '<a href="updateMooring.php?Number2=${1}&id='. $id .'">${1}</a>', $viewedResult);
```

Comment: Ugh, I hate these quick accepts, just wait a while to see if there are different/better answers out there PwnageAtPwn, some people are still hitting their keyboards.

Comment: @owlstead, he can always change it later if a better answer is posted.

Comment: That's true of course :) It seems your answer is fitting his use case though. Sometimes simple does it. I wonder though if the input is certain to be correct in advance, if it isn't, then the answer is accepting a bit much, e.g. "#!/-" would fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

I would split up the regular expression in two, as I think you want to match something like `\d{1..4}[-/]?\d{1..4}` where the first and second set of digits total 4. It's probably better just to look for `(\d+[-/]/d+)` and do a check afterwards if the total digits size is correct, e.g. finding all matches of `(\d+)` in the result, and programmatically check their length.

In general, I would pay close attention to what exactly is *allowed input*, and what (error) you will get if the input *does not match*. Splitting things up will make it much easier to show a correct error message, such as "number of digits in mooring spot incorrect" (which is I presume what this is about).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of Number2, then use:

```
Number2\s*=\s*([^;"]*)[;"]
```

And then use the first capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question: why not using this regular expression `/#!([0-9A-Z/-]{1,4})/` ?

Side note: the `{1,4}` blocks you will retrieving the value `04-072` (it's 6 chars long).

Hope that helps :)